# How do i completely discharge a capacitors entire load in a fraction of a second?

Tags: capacitor, storage, tesla-coil

I'm trying to build a tesla coil, and it seems like the capacitors in tesla coils drop their entire load quickly. I tried researching, but i could only find how to safely discharge capacitors. I want to store up the electricity in the capacitor, and then release it all in a very short period of time. Could somebody tell me how I would wire it to do that?

Comment: tesla coil doesn't do complete discharge, and uses spark gaps to do the switching,  spark gaps will outperform regular semiconductors fir this task.

Comment: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/h4x898/tesla-driver/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't discharge that quickly in TC, they rather charge quickly in original design of Tesla. The caps do charge trough a rotating spark gap at the time where a peak voltage (regarding the mains sine wave) is present. The spark gap rotates synchronously with the mains voltage, a synchronous motor spins the rotating gap.
Once the capacitor is full it begins to dischrage into a primary coil, and resonating phenomena occurs, in LC circuit the current flows back and forth until the energy vanishes.
Therfore no ultra short pulse discharge is present in TC, indeed you need high quality capacitors, Tesla used cups filled with oil.

Answer (score 2):

Create the best short circuit you can and allow as much current as possible to flow.  That's all there is to it.

The inductance of the circuit will limit how quickly you can establish this current, and the resistance will limit the current once it's flowing. The capacitor will contribute some of each.

Comment: So your saying that the capacitors in a Tesla Coil don't release everything at once?

Comment: Nothing in the universe happens 'at once' - all capacitors take time to discharge, regardless of what kind of circuit they're in.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Dear friend this equivalent circuit for TESLA coil can be usefull for you to understand the concept.
As rightly said by #Jasen, the tesla coil uses spark gaps to do the switching. In One of its kind they use Transistor, Thyristors, MOSFET or IGBT for this switching.

See this example for creating small Tesla coils.
[image]

There are many resources online which can help you build real high voltage Tesla coils.

Comment: So both the spark gap and the capacitor are hooked up to the primary coil? I noticed it in the first diagram you showed.

Comment: 2222A is a lot of A :P